# Probability: How many dice are needed

Tags: probability, dice

I have a scenario where I am trying to understand how many different approaches I need to consider starting, to solve a given real-world problem in order to 'guarantee' that at least one of the approaches succeeds (i.e. that there is a solution). Suppose that each approach has a probability of (say) 90% of solving the problem. How many different approaches should be started so that there is a 'good chance' at least one succeeds? I realise 'guarantee' and 'good chance' are not ideal terminologies.

I think that this dice analogy is accurate:

Suppose I have n dice and these are all thrown once only in one shot.
What is n for a reasonable probability that at least one dice will be a 6?

Comment: From what I have seen I believe that it may be like this like if something is a 50% chance you should roll them twice which will be a good chance because 2 times 50% is 100% which is an absolute probability

Comment: Regarding your post: that's not correct. Following your logic, an event with $80 \%$ probability cannot happen twice, as that would have a $80 \% \cdot 2 = 160 \%$ chance. The correct reasoning is as follows: the probability that none succeeds is $(0.5)^2 = 0.25$, so the probability that at least one succeeds is $1 - (0.5)^2 = 0.75$.